# pytest run only the changed file?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm fairly new to Python, trying to learn the toolsets.

I've figured out how to get `py.test -f` to watch my tests as I code. One thing I haven't been able to figure out is if there's a way to do a smarter watcher, that works like Ruby's Guard library.

Using guard + minitest the behavior I get is if I save a file like `my_class.rb` then `my_class_test.rb` is executed, and if I hit `enter` in the cli it runs all tests.

With pytest so far I haven't been able to figure out a way to only run the test file corresponding to the last touched file, thus avoiding the wait for the entire test suite to run until I've got the current file passing.

How would you pythonistas go about that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

One possibility is using [pytest-testmon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-testmon) together with [pytest-watch](https://github.com/joeyespo/pytest-watch).

It uses [coverage.py](http://coverage.readthedocs.org/) to track which test touches which lines of code, and as soon as you change a line of code, it re-runs all tests which execute that line in some way.

Comment: That's working pretty well for me. Thanks very much for the suggestion!

Comment: in coveragepy 5.0 this would be native ( [see this post](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201810/who_tests_what_is_here.html))

Comment: can you elaborate on how you combine these?

Comment: @endolith See the last line of the "Usage" section of https://pypi.org/project/pytest-testmon/

Comment: Can you elaborate in your answer?  Depending on links to other sites is discouraged because of link rot, etc

Comment: Which has actually happened in this case

Answer (score 23):

To add to **@The Compiler**'s answer above, you can get [pytest-testmon](https://github.com/tarpas/pytest-testmon/) and [pytest-watch](https://github.com/joeyespo/pytest-watch) to play together by using pytest-watch's `--runner` option:

```sh
ptw --runner "pytest --testmon"
```

Or simply:

```sh
ptw -- --testmon
```

Comment: it seems a bit slow... Is there any way to speed it up?

Answer (score 9):

The fastest setup I got was when I combines @lmiguelvargasf @BenR and @TheCompiler answer into this

```
ptw --runner "pytest --picked --testmon"
```

---

you first gotta have them installed by

```
pip3 install pytest-picked pytest-testmon pytest-watch
```

Answer (score 8):

There is also [pytest-xdist](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-xdist) which has a feature called:

> --looponfail: run your tests repeatedly in a subprocess. After each run py.test waits until a file in your project changes and then re-runs the previously failing tests. This is repeated until all tests pass after which again a full run is performed.

Comment: This solution is the best of this SO thread. It is simpler than testmon+watch and it worked with async tests (with pytest-trio) where the other solution failed.

Comment: as of pytest-xdist 3.0.2, the `-looponfail` argument has been deprecated.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using `git` as version control, you could consider using [`pytest-picked`](https://github.com/anapaulagomes/pytest-picked). This is a plugin that according to the docs:

> Run the tests related to the unstaged files or the current branch

**Demo**

[image]

#### Basic features

- Run only tests from modified test files
- Run tests from modified test files first, followed by all unmodified tests

#### Usage

```sh
pytest --picked
```